# How does Terraform deal with CoreOS/etcd2 on node failure?

Tags: coreos, etcd, terraform

I have been using terraform to create a CoreOs Cluster on Digital Ocean just fine. My question was addressed [here](http://maxenglander.com/2015/06/09/etcd-clusters-with-terraform.html) but nearly a year has passed
which seems like 10 on a fast pace projects like etcd2 and terraform. IMHO, if the master fails terraform will create another instance with the exact same configurantion, but according to the free discovery coreos service the cluster will be full and all the slaves will have the wrong ip to connect to the etcd2 master. In the case of a minion failure, the master ip wont be an issue, but I still wont be able to join a full cluster.

How does terraform deal with this kind of problem? Is there a solution or am I still binded to a hacky solution like the link above?

If I run `terraform taint node1`. It there a way to notify the dicovery service this change?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform doesn't replace configuration management tools like Ansible, Chef and Puppet.

This can be solved using a setup where, say, a Ansible run is triggered to reconfigure the slaves when the master is reprovisioned. The ansible inventory in this case, would have been update by terraform with the right ip, and the slave ansible role can pick this up and configure appropriately.

There are obviously other ways to do this, but it is highly recommended that you couple a proper CM tool with Terraform and propagate such changes.